# How to send notices to members who have different membership roles?

Tags: laravel

**Immediately, I want to ask as I asked in the title.**
I Have controller like this:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    //

    $this->validate($request, [
        'status'=> 'required|min:1|max:2',
        'subject' => 'required|min:10|max:255',
        'body' => 'required|min:10|max:100000'
    ]);
    if ($request->status == 1){
        $this->validate($request, [
            'email' => 'required|email',
        ]);
        $user = User::whereEmail($request->email)->firstOrFail();
        $notice = new Notice();
        $notice->user_id = $user->id;
        $notice->title = $request->subject;
        $notice->priority = $request->priority;
        $notice->body = $request->body;
        $notice->status = 0;

        if ($request->hasFile('featured')){
            $featured = $request->featured;
            $featured_new_name = time().$featured->getClientOriginalName();
            $featured->move('uploads/posts', $featured_new_name);
            $notice->file = 'uploads/posts/'. $featured_new_name;
        }
        $notice->save();
        session()->flash('message', "Send Message to ".$user->name." Successful!");
        Session::flash('type', 'success');
        Session::flash('title', 'Message Send Success!');
        return redirect()->route('adminMessage.create');
    }
    else {

        $users = User::all();

        if ($request->hasFile('featured')){
            $featured = $request->featured;
            $featured_new_name = time().$featured->getClientOriginalName();
            $featured->move('uploads/posts', $featured_new_name);
            $attachment = 'uploads/posts/'. $featured_new_name;
        }
        foreach ($users as $user){

            $notice = new Notice();
            $notice->user_id = $user->id;
            $notice->title = $request->subject;
            $notice->priority = $request->priority;
            $notice->body = $request->body;
            $notice->status = 0;

            if ($request->hasFile('featured')){
                $notice->file  = $attachment;
            }
            $notice->save();
        }
        session()->flash('message', "Send Message to all Users Successful!");
        Session::flash('type', 'success');
        Session::flash('title', 'Message Send Success!');
        return redirect()->route('adminMessage.create');
    }
}
```

**I Have 2 status in this field:**
For Status 1, I send for selected member (Only One)
For Status 2, I send for all User use `$user= User::all();`

So I need for help with Send Notice with Membership_role
I Have Memberships Tables, for example like this:

```
=========================
| id |  name  |  count  |
-------------------------
|  1 |  free  |  200    |
|  2 |  free  |  200    |
|  3 |  free  |  200    |
|  4 |  free  |  200    |
```

**How do I send a message to Membership Id: 2,3,4**

Comment: the membership is related as a foreign key at the users table?

Comment: Membership_role is a model, hasMany relationship with User model?

Comment: Yes, I have foreign key at the users table, so my problem only how to send message with separate, example: $membership = Membership::whereId(2,3,4)->get();

Comment: You're doing the querys in the wrong table, if you want to retrieve users by their membership you must use ```User::where('membership_id',$the_id)```

Comment: `User::where('membership_id',$the_id)`, how to separate id? `User::where('membership_id','2,3,4')` like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is a property at the `User` model, you can use querys to find the user or users you want.

```php
/*
I use a switch just in case you have more than 2 notice statuses to handle
the sendTo functions are functions declared in your controller to handle the cases.  
*/
switch($notice->status){
    /*Query the user by the membership id to send the notice*/
    case 1:
        $user = User::where('membership_id',$the_membership)->first();
        return $this->sendTo($user);
    case 2:
    /*Get all users*/
        $users = User::all();
        return $this->sendTo($users);
   /*Handle other notice statuses*/
    default:
        return $this->sendToDefault();
}
```

Comment: Nah, I have finished this section, but how can I send a notice to membership_id = 2,3,4 at the same time?

Comment: Use ```User::whereIn('membership_id', [2, 3,4])``` to retrieve the users with those memberships.

Comment: `User::whereIn('membership_id', [2, 3,4])` Thank you, this code solve my problem....